# How to control multiple stepper motor with raspberry pi using L298n

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi3

I m trying to control two stepper motor using raspberry pi. The script below does the job, but I want to control two where both can run simultaneously and in opposite directions as well. I m new to this but I tired to use two different scripts than run it simultaneously with bash like this `python script1.py & python script2.py &`. that did not work I also tried to put both code in a two loops and I tried to put it in a separate function and run it simultaneously that did not work. Due to my limited knowledge I was not able to solve this.

````
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 

out1 = 13
out2 = 11
out3 = 15
out4 = 12

i=0
positive=0
negative=0
y=0



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(out1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out4,GPIO.OUT)

print ("First calibrate by giving some +ve and -ve values.....")


try:
   while(1):
      GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
      x = int(input())
      if x>0 and x<=400:
          for y in range(x,0,-1):
              if negative==1:
                  if i==7:
                      i=0
                  else:
                      i=i+1
                  y=y+2
                  negative=0
              positive=1
              #print((x+1)-y)
              if i==0:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==1:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==2:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==3:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==4:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==5:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==6:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==7:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              if i==7:
                  i=0
                  continue
              i=i+1
      
      
      elif x<0 and x>=-400:
          x=x*-1
          for y in range(x,0,-1):
              if positive==1:
                  if i==0:
                      i=7
                  else:
                      i=i-1
                  y=y+3
                  positive=0
              negative=1
              #print((x+1)-y) 
              if i==0:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==1:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==2:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==3:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==4:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==5:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==6:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==7:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              if i==0:
                  i=7
                  continue
              i=i-1 

              
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup() ```
````